# Why does my Xcode build keep failing?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

Any idea why I can't build my iOS app with Xcode? I've successfully built it for the simulators many times, so the app itself isn't the problem. When Xcode fails, it gives me this error message: "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain."

Simple enough, right? But: In my login keychain, I have two certificates, "iPhone Developer: [My First Name] [My Last Name] ([alphanumeric ID])," and "iPhone Distribution: [Name of My Company]." Both expire in August 2012. "This certificate is valid," Keychain Access tells me about both of them.

In Organizer, I have three provisioning profiles: "[Name of Company] Distribution," "[Name of App]," and "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *." All three of these have expiration dates in the future. They're all on the platform iOS Profile. The first two have an app identifier of [ALPHANUMERICCODE].com.[nameofcompany].*, the third has an app identifier of simply [ALPHANUMERICCODE].*. But get this: All three have "Valid signing identity not found" under Status.

I've done a lot of searching and can't find any examples of anyone reporting both the certificates and the provisioning profiles being present but still being unable to build an archive in Xcode. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got the WWDR Intermediate Certificate installed? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Just a thought, try making a new app id and matching provisioning profiles with the bundle id formatted like "com.companyname.appname"

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with keys. In keychain access, there is a section called keys. I'm thinking you are missing the keys that were used to sign your provisioning profiles.